# How to read value from bytes array of odd size?

Tags: go, byte

How to read value from byte array of odd size like if we have a `byte array` size of 1,3,5,7,9. Is there a way to get the value directly?

In case i want to read 3 bytes.

if i use:

```
binary.BigEndian.Uint16(buf[0:3])
```

then it only reads first two bytes and
if i use:

```
binary.BigEndian.Uint32(buf[0:3])
```

then i get a panic.

Is there a way to read value from any odd size byte array?

Comment: Create a slice with 0x00 byte and append buf[0:3] to it, before read as uint32

Answer (score 0):

If you have an array with three bytes in it, it does not hold two 16-bit integers, nor one 32-bit integer.  It may hold one 24-bit integer, or one 16-bit integer and one 8-bit integer.  You need to decide what, if anything, to do about this.

The way to figure out *what* to do about it is to answer, manually, the question of what it means to read a 32-bit integer from an array that contains the byte sequence `\x01`, `\x02`, `\x03`.  Is that the integer value `0x00010203`, or is it the the integer value `0x01020300`, or is it an error, or what?  Once you know the answer to *this* question, you can write your Go code.